# Is there a way to find if a driver needs to be rolled back using powershell

Tags: drivers, powershell

Is there a way to find if a driver needs to be rolled back using powershell?

Also, is there any powershell command to know if atleast one version of a driver is installed in the system?

I was trying to to do rollback operation of adriver using powershell commands. I couldn't find any specific command as such for this and using pnputil.exe to uninstall the current version of the driver.  Before uninstalling, just wanted to find out, if there is any specific command or tool which can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell cannot determine if a driver must be rolled back. Only you can do that by observing operation of the driver.

A better approach is to use Device Manager to update and/or uninstall a driver.

After uninstalling, you can try an earlier driver.

Remember (if Windows 10) that the current driver in the Microsoft Catalogue may be installed anyway.